# C# WPF application using data binding, data templates and observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections, binding

I am making a program in C# WPF using data binding, data templates and observable collection. I am basing my application on the Data Binding Demo from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771319(v=vs.90).aspx. For some reason I cannot make my program display any data from binding. Debugging tells me that my Records class collection works but on this line:

`records_collection_db = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["records_collection_db"]);`

my 'records_collection_db' variable in null whereas it should be holding some data. I suspect that that my CollectionViewSource in xaml line is set incorrectly but I don't really know how to fix it. It is my first program in WPF and so I don't have much experience on the subject. At this moment the only visible difference between my code and the one from sample is that my initial window is... a  where in the demo it an

Code (or at least shortened version of it):

---

**Record class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int Lp;
        private string group;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int _Lp
        {
            get { return this.Lp; }
            set { this.Lp = value; OnPropertyChanged("_Lp"); }
        }

        public string _group
        {
            get { return this.group; }
            set { this.group = value; OnPropertyChanged("_group"); }
        }


        public Record(int Lp, string group)
        {
            this.Lp = Lp;
            this.group = group;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Initial window**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {                
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var newWindow1 = new Audyt_window();
            newWindow1.Show();
        }    
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=Mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="text_style" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
        </Style>        

    </Window.Resources>    

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Height="93" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Zamknij" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,223,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Rekordy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Height="52" Click="Button_Click_2" />
        <Button Content="Dodaj" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Operational window**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Audyt_window : Window
    {       
        CollectionViewSource records_collection;

        private ObservableCollection<Record> records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        public ObservableCollection<Record> Records
        {
            get { return this.records; }
            set { this.records = value; }
        }

        public Audyt_window()
        {        
            load_temp_data();    

            InitializeComponent();
            records_collection = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["records_collection"]);
        }

        private void load_temp_data()
        {
            Record rek1 = new Record(601, "Gr1", "Pro1", "Pyt1", 600001, "Kat1", false, false);
            Record rek2 = new Record(602, "Gr2", "Pro2", "Pyt2", 600002, "Kat2", false, false);
            Record rek3 = new Record(603, "Gr3", "Pro3", "Pyt3", 600003, "Kat3", false, false);
            this.Records.Add(rek1);
            this.Records.Add(rek2);
            this.Records.Add(rek3);
        }            
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Audyt_window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Audyt" 
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=Records}" x:Key="records_collection" />

        <Style x:Key="text_style" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Records_Template" DataType="{x:Type src:Record}">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Navy" Padding="7" Name="Record_List_Border" Margin="3" Width="345">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Name="textblock_Lp"
                               Style="{StaticResource text_style}"
                               Text="Lp: "
                               >
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Background="Azure" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                               Name="datablock_Lp"
                               Style="{StaticResource text_style}"
                               Text="{Binding Path=_Lp}"
                               >
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                               Name="datablock_group"
                               Style="{StaticResource text_style}"
                               Text="{Binding Path=_group}"
                               >
                    </TextBlock>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Border Padding="10">
        <Grid>

            <ListBox Name="Hits_View_List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Height="525" Width="400" Margin="420,0,0,0" 
                 BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DimGray" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource records_collection}}"             
                 >                    
            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: There should be records_collection = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["records_collection"]); in the text of my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Audyt_window` you set the source of your binding of the `CollectionViewSource` to `{x:Static Application.Current}`, but the `Records` `ObservableCollection` is declared inside your Audyt_window

Change:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=Records}" x:Key="records_collection" />
```

To

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Records}" x:Key="records_collection" />
```

And it should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

you Name your collectionviewsource

```
x:Key="records_collection"
```

and you are searching for `records_collection_db`... that cant match

```
records_collection_db = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["records_collection_db"]);
```

Change the Key or Change the string to the right name

Comment: Thank you for that fast responce. Unfortunatelly it's just my spelling mistake while writing this post and not the real issue ;/

Comment: But the failure is in the text AND in your code of `Operational window`